# C++ apply standard library algorithms to functions

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Is there a way to apply non-modifying standard library algorithms to discrete functions instead of containers?

For example, consider the following function

```
int sqr(int i)
{
    return i*i;
}
```

How can I use `std::find` or `std::lower_bound` to search for the value `49`, i.e. the algorithm should return `7`? The easiest way would be to put the returns into a vector and apply the algorithm to the vector -- but this is obviously inefficient.

Comment: These algorithms require both begin and end iterators. What would you pass as `end` - an iterator to [Aleph Naught](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number)?

Comment: @AmiTavory: Unbounded range iterators aren't uncommon, e.g. `std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin)`. You could build such a thing for searching integers if you really wanted to.

Comment: @AmiTavory: yes, Aleph Naught if my computer can handle that. If not, a reasonable upper bound as in any other algorithm as well.

Comment: If I understand the question, you are asking about algorithms to search the possible solution space of a function.  This is not something that lies in the domain of the standard library.  It is instead more related to linear algebra and function solvers that might be found in something like BLAS.

Comment: OK, then. I agree with @paddy that a numerical library, not based on iterators, would probably be better for this sort of stuff. Nonethless, it is possible (wrote something out below).

Comment: @Paddy: why not? In any optimization routine one has to provide a search region, e.g. in the form of initial brackets. In the same way one would specify the search region as an index range here. But the background of my question is less general, it's just container access through a function.

Comment: @KerrekSB It wouldn't take that much code: you could slap a boost iterator facade on a a boost counting iterator to obtain an aleph-ephes enumerator (a special "end" iterator would evaluate as false when compared to a concrete-number iterator).

Comment: @AmiTavory: My biggest conceptual objection is that this turns `find` into a partial function that may not terminate. So it's probably the wrong approach for a real computer program.

Comment: @AmiTavory Aleph Naught is a _cardinal_. An iterator must be an _ordinal_. One must pass omega instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hypothetically, you could use something like [`boost::iterator::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html). E.g., the following finds that 4 is the number whose square is 16:

```
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>


using namespace std;


int main(int, char**)
{

    auto f = std::find_if(
        boost::make_counting_iterator<int>(0),
        boost::make_counting_iterator<int>(20),
        [](int i){return i * i == 16;});
    cout << std::distance(
        boost::make_counting_iterator<int>(0),
        f) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think that this approach is problematic in many ways. In the above, in particular, note that it searches for such numbers up to 20.